# incomplete prefix in an XML node

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe, msxml

need a node with prefix, but he does it the right way, is a failure of the way I do? or is a compiler bug?

main module code

```
    function Generar_Addenda(PathCFD : String; ValidaOnly : Integer) : Integer;
const
  xmlns = 'xmlns=""';             (* Cadena String a Borrar, (se genera al obtener la interaz Factura) *)
var
  XMLFactura : IXMLDocument;
  Factura : IXMLFactura;
  CFD : TCFD;
begin

  Try
    CFD := TCFD.Create(cfdV22);       // AQUI CREO UNA INSTANCIA DEL CFD, PARA TENER LA CLASE COMPLETA
    CFD.LoadFromFile(PathCFD);       // AQUI CARGO EL XML YA SELLADO, LISTO PARA PEGAR LA ADDENDA

    XMLFactura := TXMLDocument.Create(Nil);
    XMLFactura.Active := True;

    Factura := GetFactura(XMLFactura);

// ************* PERSONALIZAR ADDENDA CHRYSLER PPY  **********************             AQUI LLENO LA ADDENDA CON LOS DATOS DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    With Factura do
     begin
       TipoDocumento := cds_cliente.FieldByName('TipoDocumento').AsString;
       TipoDocumentoFiscal := cds_Cliente.FieldByName('TipoDocumentoFiscal').AsString;   
       Version := cds_Cliente.FieldByName('Version').AsString;
      ......
      .....
    end;

    FACTURA.OwnerDocument.Options := [doAutoPrefix];


    CFD.Datos.Addenda.ChildNodes.Add(Factura);

    Factura.SetAttributeNS('xmlns:PPY','', 'http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY');
    Factura.Attributes['xsi:schemaLocation'] :=  'http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY/PPY.XSD';

    CFD.SaveToFile('C:\Paso\CFD_PRUEBA_ADDENDA_CHRYSLER.XML');
  Finally
     ......
     ......

  End;
```

I made ​​changes in the interface Intf_PPY I made were the following, in PPY prepend node name will factura

```
    function Getfactura(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLFactura;
function Loadfactura(const FileName: string): IXMLFactura;
function Newfactura: IXMLFactura;

const
  TargetNamespace =
   'http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY'; // xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY/PPY.XSD"';

implementation

{ Global Functions }

function Getfactura(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLFactura;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('PPY:factura', TXMLFactura, TargetNamespace) as IXMLFactura;
end;

function Loadfactura(const FileName: string): IXMLFactura;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('PPY:factura', TXMLFactura, TargetNamespace) as IXMLFactura;
end;

function Newfactura: IXMLFactura;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('PPY:factura', TXMLFactura, TargetNamespace) as IXMLFactura;
end;
```

and this is what I find, with the **nodes note, otroscargos, part** no prefix, but with the namespace included within them

```
    <Addenda>
      <PPY:factura tipoDocumento="PPY" TipoDocumentoFiscal="FA" version="1.0" serie="A" folioFiscal="451" fecha="2012-06-20" montoTotal="9960.98" referenciaProveedor="A 451" xmlns:PPY="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY/PPY.XSD">
         <PPY:moneda tipoMoneda="USD" tipoCambio="1.0000"/>
         <PPY:proveedor codigo="20215" nombre="NOMBRE DE LA EMPRESA S.A. DE C.V."/>
         <PPY:destino codigo="8476" nombre="PLANTA DE MOTORES 4 CILINDROS - SALTILLO"/>
         <nota xmlns="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY">Addenda de Prueba</nota>
         <otrosCargos xmlns="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY" codigo="V6" monto="1373.93"/>
         <PPY:partes>
            <part xmlns="http://www.dfdchryslerdemexico.com.mx/Addenda/PPY" numero="123456" cantidad="1.0000" unidadDeMedida="EA" precioUnitario="8587.0500" montoDeLinea="8587.05">
               <references ordenCompra="XYZ6675" releaseRequisicion="XYZ4218000" ammendment="A"/>
               <nota>Probando Addenda</nota>
            </part>
         </PPY:partes>
      </PPY:factura>
   </Addenda>
```

I'm doing something wrong? or is there another way that works?

thanks

Comment: What do you expect to _see_? how this can be a compiler bug, if it compiles fine?

Comment: **PPY prefix** must appear on all items, and if you look at the elements **nota, otrosCargos, part, references** are not part of the name

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the namespace ad prefix are registered with the DOM before you can use them effectively on child nodes and attributes.  Your `nota`, `ostrosCargos`, and `part` nodes end up with their own `xmlns` attributes if you are specifying a namespace when creating them, but you did not previously register that namespace with the `factura` node.  It is not enough to just create an `xmlns` attribute manually like you are currently doing.  You need to actually register the namespace with the DOM so it knows about it and can use it when needed.

Have a look at this discussion on the Embarcadero forum for tips on how to work with namespaced nodes in the implementation code that the XML Data Binding wizard creates:

[Creating a doc with two namespaces](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64760)

Comment: **all nodes are registered with the function RegisterChildNodes Afterconstruction of TXMLFactura, others are collections**   
`FCargosCreditos := CreateCollection(TXMLFactura_cargosCreditosList, IXMLFactura_cargosCreditos, 'cargosCreditos') as IXMLFactura_cargosCreditosList;
  FOtrosCargos := CreateCollection(TXMLFactura_otrosCargosList, IXMLFactura_otrosCargos, 'otrosCargos') as IXMLFactura_otrosCargosList;`

Comment: 'RegisterChildNode('otrosCargos', TXMLFactura_otrosCargos);
  RegisterChildNode('partes', TXMLFactura_partes);'